# Is there a command to get the time of day/night in an app?

Tags: android, time, integer

Basically, is there a command in droid that will allow me to check the time on the user's phone and have it returned?  Where I can then assign the time to an int?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you even attempt to look in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long currentTime=Date.getTime();
```